# Having trouble converting point that's on a rotated view with a (0, .5) anchor point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgpoint

I have the following view set up:

[image]

Where the anchor point for V3 is (0, .5) and it can be rotated by a UIPanGestureRecognizer that's attached to V4. I'm trying to translate a point on V4 to V1s coordinate space (so I can attach a subview to V1 that appears over the center of V4) and I can't get it to place correctly. I have the following code:

```
CGSize targetImageViewSize = CGSizeMake(v4.frame.size.width / 2, v4.frame.size.height / 2);
//find the point that will place the target in the center of v4 when attached as a subview to v1 (i.e. in its center)
CGPoint convertedTargetImageViewOrigin = [v1 convertPoint:CGPointMake((v4.frame.size.width - targetImageViewSize.width) / 2, (v4.frame.size.height - targetImageViewSize.height) / 2) fromView:v4];
UIImageView *targetImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(convertedTargetImageViewOrigin.x, convertedTargetImageViewOrigin.y, targetImageViewSize.width, targetImageViewSize.height)];
targetImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TargetIcon"];
targetImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(v3.degreesRotated);
[v1 addSubview:targetImageView];
```

I've also tried rotating the point to no avail:

```
convertedTargetImageViewOrigin = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(convertedTargetImageViewOrigin, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(v3.degreesRotated));
```

To be clear, I don't this target to appear over v4 while the user is rotating, just briefly when the user taps v1. Any help as to why I can't get the correct point would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try working with centers. Something like `CGPoint convertedTargetImageViewCenter = [v1 convertPoint:v4.center fromView:v4];`. Then set the `center` property of the image view to `convertedTargetImageViewCenter`.

Comment: Don't forget the following in the documentation for `UIView frame`: *"Warning
If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored."*.

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks I changed to the center, and it seems to be more consistent in how it's missing, so maybe it was correct to do that but something else is at play. And yeah changed from frame to bounds as well, good call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HangarRash pointed me in the right direction by suggesting that I use `v4`'s `center` property instead of manually calculating the origin. After that, I just had to adjust for the fact that `v4`'s `center` property is in terms of `v3`'s coordinate space when using `convertPoint:fromView`, and then it worked!

```
CGSize targetImageViewSize = CGSizeMake(v4.frame.size.width / 2, v4.frame.size.height / 2);
CGPoint targetImageViewCenter = v4.center;
CGPoint convertedTargetImageViewCenter = [v1 convertPoint:targetImageViewCenter fromView:v3];

UIImageView *targetImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, targetImageViewSize.width, targetImageViewSize.height)];
targetImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TargetIcon"];
targetImageView.center = convertedTargetImageViewCenter;
[self.targetImageViews addObject:targetImageView];
targetImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(v3.angle);
[v1 addSubview: targetImageView];
```